# How can I migrate Documents from MS Office Live to Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, microsoft

Is there a easy way to migrate **a large number** of MS Office Live documents to Google Docs? Does Google has some tool for that?

Comment: As per my comment on Luca's answer - is this for a large number of documents, or just a few?

Answer (score 1):

...did you try UPLOAD button in your google doc page ?

[MS Office Live] --> [download to your desktop] --> [UPLOAD to Google docs]

Comment: I think user84693 is looking for a way to do this in bulk, but that's not altogether clear...

Answer (score -1):

Does Office Live also sync to your desktop (or allow you download all files in one go)?
If it does, you can then sync this folder with [Syncdocs](http://www.syncdocs.com/) to Google docs. It has been working very well for me.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?